# How to use the formData API to send a JSON Object that contains another Object?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data

I have created a HTML-form like this:

```
<form id="student__form">
    <div class="form__name-section">
        <div class="form__input-group">
            <label for="firstName">Firstname:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="student['firstName']">
        </div>
        <div class="form__input-group">
            <label for="lastName">Lastname:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="student['lastName']">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__info-section">
        <div class="form__info-section__left-column">
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
            </div>
        <div class="form__input-group">
            <label for="eMail">e-Mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="eMail" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am using the formData API in Javascript to parse the input-data into a JSON object. I read up on the formData API on [this](https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/get-form-values-as-json) link.

Following the linked tutorial, I can easily obtain the form-input as a JSON:

```
{
  student['firstName']: 'Jennifer', 
  student['lastName']: 'Adams', 
  address: 'some address ', 
  email: 'jennifer.adams@gmail.com'
}
```

It's almost what I want, but not exactly. I would like the student-information to be contained in an object itself:

```
{
  student: 
  {
    firstName: 'Jennifer', 
    lastName: 'Adams'
  } 
  address: 'some address ', 
  email: 'jennifer.adams@gmail.com'
}
```

This is essential for me, since I am sending this JSON as a POST-request to my server. I have confirmed that the latter JSON will work, while the first doesn't. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You are mixing things up. If you use Thymeleaf, you normally use a `Controller` to accept a form POST (See [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) for more info). If you really want to keep using a REST API with `RestController`, then you should convert the contents of the form to JSON in JavaScript and do an AJAX request from JavaScript to your REST API.

Comment: thx a lot for your answer, Wim! I have changed my question, because I think with the knowledge I have my goal is achieved best not using thymeleaf, but the formData API. I will definitely read your blog post though and familiarize myself with thymeleaf.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe — The OP **is**  converting the contents of the form to JSON in JavaScript. It's just that left the code for that behind a link to a tutorial site.

Comment: @JaredSmith can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I have deleted my comment because after your edit it makes no sense. Now I don't understand what your question is. Do please note that using `Object.fromEntries` on formData entries is NOT safe. Consider: `const frm = document.createElement('form'); frm.innerHTML = '<input type="number" value="1" name="foo" /><input type="number" value="2" name="foo" />'; const frmData = new FormData(frm);`. In that case `frmData.getAll('foo')` will give you the array `["1", "2"]`, as expected. `[...frmData.entries()]` cashes out to `[['foo', '1'], ['foo', '2']]`. But this means that...

Comment: ...[cont'd] now `Object.fromEntries(frmData.entries())` will just be `{ foo: '2' }` and you've *lost data from the form*. It is actually *very* common for multiple form controls to have the same `name` attribute. As for your question, please post the *exact* error you're getting as well as any necessary context to understand it.

Comment: allright, thx a lot Jared! I will read up on this. ... I have posted my error message, but the question that I have is really: How do I get the JSON to look the way I want it to? Or is this not even a requirement for my POST request?